# Can I combine multiple dicts with the same name in Python?

Tags: python, json, api, dictionary

I'm trying to create a new list from an API return in python. The purpose of this API call is to pull a list of driver's names, and pair them to a vehicle ID native to the API service. The code currently looks like this:

```
url = url

headers = {
    "accept": "application/json",
    "authorization": auth
}

response = requests.get(url, headers=headers)
response = response.json()
for doc in response['data']:
    try:
        doc['id'],
        doc['staticAssignedDriver']['name']
    except:
        pass
    else:
        names = {
            doc['staticAssignedDriver']['name']: doc['id']
        }
        names.update(names)
        print(type(names))
        print(names)
```

This prints a list of unique names and id's as individual dicts. IE:

```
{'name1':'id1'}
<class 'dict'>
{'name2':'id2'}
<class 'dict'>
```

Until I have all of my name:id pairs from my API.

But I'd like to make that a single dict, as such:

```
{'name1': 'id1', 'name2': 'id2'}
```

It seems like each new name/id pair ends up being its own var 'names'. Is there a way to make this its own singular dict, instead of individual?

Comment: *{'name1': 'id1', 'name2': 'id2'}* is not a list - it's a dictionary. *names.update(names)* is effectively a noop. Python dictionaries don't have names

Comment: Thank you Pingu. I'm still new to Python and mostly self/Google taught, so I'm still trying to learn all the terms and quirks. Thank you for the feedback.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

When you do `names = {whatever: whatever}`, you always create a new dictionary with exactly one key and value. If you want to have only one dictionary that you update over and over, create the dictionary outside of the loop, and just assign a single value into it at a time:

```
names = {}

for doc in ...:
   ...
   names[doc['staticAssignedDriver']['name']] = doc['id']
```

Answer (score 0):

```
x = [{'name1':'id1'},
    {'name2':'id2'}]
d = {}
for dct in x:
    d.update({key: value for key, value in dct.items()})

print(d)
{'name1': 'id1', 'name2': 'id2'}
```

Comment: Please read [answer] and [edit] your answer to contain an explanation as to why this code would actually solve the problem at hand. Always remember that you're not only solving the problem, but are also educating the OP and any future readers of this post